# How to use LUIS entities with choice prompts?

Tags: javascript, botframework

I have a botframework waterfall step with a ChoicePrompt, something like this:

```
constructor(id) {
  ...
  this.addDialog(new ChoicePrompt(CP));
  this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(this.initialDialogId, [
    this.WF_select.bind(this)
    // more steps
  ]
  ...
}

async WF_select(step) {
   ...
   return step.prompt(CP, {prompt: heroCard, choices: choiceArray})
}
```

This works fine. But if I've already gotten an answer for the prompt from a LUIS entity I wouldn't need to actually prompt the user. Except there is no guarantee the answer is a valid choice. Is there a way to use the entity as an input to the prompt? The prompt has all the logic to validate the answer, especially with `allowPartialMatches:true` in the recognizer. How could this be handled?